# Detecting JQuery UI Slider event keycodes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

In order to gather some statistics on how users interact with an web application, I would like to know how they use a certain JQuery UI Slider. Specifically, I would like to know whether they used the mouse or the keyboard (the arrow keys) to manipulate the slider.

My code is as follows:

```
$test.slider({range: "min", step: 0.1, slide: updatePosition, stop: slideEnd, start: slideStart});
```

How would I detect, within my functions `slideStart` and `slideEnd`, whether the arrow keys were pressed or the mouse was used? Would I have to modify the plugin source? That's what I would like to avoid.

Would adding another handler to $test for click/keypresses be the best bet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way that seems the cleanest. I just added:

```
$test.keyup(slideKey);
```

Where $test is my slider div. I had to use `keyup()` rather than `keypress()` to catch the arrow keys in Chrome.

In the slideKey function, I just use the event object passed in.

```
function slideKey(e)
{
    console.log(e.keycode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind an event listener to the `slidechange` and/or `slide` events. The first parameter is an event object which contains the `originalEvent`. Its `type` attribute contains what you are looking for.

```
$test.bind('slide slidechange', function(event, ui) {
    if (event.originalEvent) {
        console.info(event.originalEvent.type);
    }
});
```

Caution! The `originalEvent` will only be present if the events were triggered by a user interaction.